# EPROCESS and ETHREAD in Windows

Tags: windows, memory, windbg

I am working on a function that will count the numbers of each progress's threads, and I saw that there's a variable named ThreadListHead in the structure EPROCESS, it points to a pointer which connect all the threads in the process. I want to ask if there's no threads in a process, what would the value be for ThreadListHead? It is a null or something? Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't have a Windows process without at least one thread.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: you can't have a *running* process without at least one thread.  But an EPROCESS represents a process object, which need not necessarily be running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThreadListHead` is a `LIST_ENTRY` structure representing a list header.

[LIST_ENTRY is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): if the list is empty then both the `Flink` and the `Blink` members point to `ThreadListHead` itself.

However, you need to be very careful about reading from `ThreadListHead`.  Since the structure of EPROCESS isn't officially documented, it might change without notice; also, you have no way of knowing how to properly synchronize access to it on multicore machines, so the thread list might be changing in unpredictable ways while you're looking at it.

Comment: Still cannot work out my function, but the teacher changed the demands, and I also learned a lot from your answer. So, thanks a lot.